# Discount percentage based on order value

Tags: discount

Please could someone share their wisdom on how to implement a custom discount percentage based on order total? I'm relatively new to Magento but have had a good look through the admin back-end of my site and these forums and can't find anything obvious.

**Example:**

- Order total £125.00 - Discount 0.0%
- Order total £200.00 - Discount 2.5%
- Order total £250.00 - Discount 5.0%
- Order total £300.00 - Discount 7.5%
- etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was being caused by the Mage_Weee.xml module being disabled. Once it was re-enabled the shopping cart price rules starting working straight away. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using shopping cart rules...
Goto admin >Promotion>Shopping cart rules> Click on Add new rules and it open a form

```
Status=Active
```

Customer Groups Select `all customer group`

```
Coupon =No Coupon
```

Then goto  tab  Conditions:Put Here conditoins

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

    Subtotal  equals or less than  125
```

and then goto Action tabs:

```
Apply:Percent of product price discount


Discount Amount:Put discount
```

Create this works for discount

Comment: The discount amount would be fixed then. How to achived this with different discounts as mentioned by OP. like 2.5%, 5.0%, 7.5%

Answer (score 0):

Check out `Promotions -> Shopping Cart Price Rules`.  You'll want to add a new rule then set up some conditionals there.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is working fine with no conditions entered however when I enter do a condition, i.e. apply 5% discount when subtotal is greater than £150, it does not get applied at the checkout stage. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is still an issue unfortunately. Can anyone help please?